# Set UILabel height programmatically Swift not working

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I m working on an app where I calculate the height of tableview cell(custom cell) dynamically.The height is calculated perfectly but the label in the cell is truncated. I also tried to set the label's height but still it shows truncated text.

[image]

In above screenshot you can see that the long text is not completely shown, 
I tried setting the label's height programmatically but it does not work.
Below is the code for setting the height:

```
let attributes = NSMutableDictionary()
attributes.setValue(MyFonts.HELVETICA_NEUE_REGULAR_15, forKey: NSFontAttributeName)

var cellSize = labelText!.boundingRectWithSize(labelSize!, options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: attributes, context: nil)

labelHeight = cellSize.size.height
customCell?.subtitleLabel?.frame.size.height = labelHeight;
```

Kindly suggest any solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

If your cell is created with auto layout you need to set

```
customCell?.subtitleLabel?.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have to take care of some points.

1. Need to override `layoutSubviews()` in custom cell, so that you can set frame for that label text
2. Number of line for label should be zero
3. Dynamic calculate the height of label
4. Dynamic cell height

I have created demo for dynamic cell.

### [Sample demo](http://jmp.sh/nRCw45v)

[image]